# Is there any code to manipulate the localstorage with any UWP

Tags: debugging, uwp

Edge DevTools Preview could manipulate local storage of a PWA APP , could i do it also ?

EdgeDevTools is a close source APP , and i googled , no document says some API or SDK could manipulate the localstorage of a PWA APP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since the UWP application is a sandbox application, in theory each application is independent of each other and cannot directly access the data of an App.

The PWA application relies on `WWAHost.exe`, but it also enjoys the treatment of UWP applications. Its data is protected and will not expose data access methods.

Best regards.